# Sort an n-element array so first k-elements are lowest in increasing order (In place algorithm)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort, counting-sort

This is a homework question that I am stuck on.

I need to sort an n-element array so that the first k-elements are the lowest and are in increasing order. For k <= n/log(n), the algorithm should be O(n).

My solutions:
A simple solution that I thought of is to heapify (O(n)) the array. Then delete the k-elements and shift the starting index of the heap/array from 0 to 1 - 2 - 3 (and so on, all the way to k). This would be O(n+k*lg(n)+k*n) = O(kn+k*lg(n)). For the given condition of k, it would be O(n^2/log(n) + n).

Another possible implementation would be to use radix sort, which would be O(n) but I have a feeling this is not the right solution because I would be sorting the entire array and they only asked to sort k elements.

You don't have to give me the answer, just a hint would be helpful.

Comment: [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm.

Comment: C++ [`std::partial_sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)

Comment: @timrau has it. Use O(n) algo to partition about kth largest then sort first k. This is O(n + k log k) and constant space.

Comment: @timrau: You or Gene should write that up as an answer. Asymptotically, that's the best solution, and in my experience QuickSelect is much faster than an in-place BuildHeap.

Comment: Radix sort could work, as long as the range of your numbers is no larger than the size of the array. I don't see how sorting the entire array would be a problem; any way you do this in place has the potential of modifying the entire array. So what if the modification results in the entire array being sorted?

Answer (score 1):

I like your heap idea. I actually think that it would work in the time bounds you listed and that there's a bit of a glitch in your analysis.

Suppose you do the following: build an in-place heap in your array, then dequeue the minimum k elements, leaving the remaining n - k elements where they are in the array. If you think about where the elements will end up, you should have the k smallest elements in the array stored at the back of the array in ascending order, and the n - k remaining elements will be at the front, in heap order. If you're having trouble seeing this, think about how heapsort works - after k dequeues, the largest k elements are in descending order at the back, and the remaining elements are heap-ordered in the front. Here, we've exchanged a min-heap for a max-heap, hence the weird ordering. As a result, if you then reverse the array at the end, you should have the k smallest elements in ascending order at the front, followed by the n - k remaining elements.

This will correctly find the k smallest elements, and the runtime is determined as follows:

- Cost of the heapify: O(n)
- Cost of k dequeues: O(k log n)
- Cost of reversing the array: O(n)
- Total cost: O(n + k log n)

Now, suppose that k ≤ n / log n. Then the runtime is

> O(n + k log n) = O(n + (n / log n) log n) = O(n)

So you're done! The algorithm works just fine. Plus, it requires O(1) auxiliary space (the heap can be built in-place, and it's possible to reverse an array in O(1) space).

You can do better, though. @timrau suggested in the comments that you use quickselect (or, more generally, any linear-time selection algorithm). These algorithms rearrange arrays to put the lowest k elements in some order in the first k slots of the array and the remaining n - k elements in the last n - k slots in some order. Doing so takes time O(n) regardless of k (nifty!). So suppose you do that, then just sort the first k elements. This takes time O(n + k log k), which is asymptotically better than the O(n + k log n)-time heap-based algorithm.

Of the known linear-time selection algorithms, both quickselect and the median-of-medians algorithms can be implemented in-place if you're careful, so the total space required for this approach is O(1).

Comment: I'm missing something here. When finished, are the minimum k elements in the first k positions of the array?

Comment: @JimMischel I believe that's what would happen if you represented everything implicitly as a heap. Depending on how you did it, you might need to reverse the array at the end, though. I'm thinking about a standard implementation of heapsort, which uses an in-place representation of a heap in order to place everything in the proper position. Am I missing something? (Also, anything else I can do to improve this answer?)

Comment: Typically, if you want to sort an array in ascending order, you build a max-heap and then build the sorted array from the back to front. For this problem, you probably want to build a min-heap *backwards*: with the minimum item at the end of the array. Then do your k SelectMin operations and put the selected item at the beginning of the array. If that's unclear, ask me to elaborate. I just re-read it and realize that it assumes some context.

Comment: @JimMischel That makes sense. If I update my answer to add in that detail, would that be sufficient for you to remove the downvote? Or are there other details you'd like me to include?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. Your change that involves reversing the array is sufficient, though, to make the answer useful enough to merit an upvote.

Comment: @JimMischel Ah, my apologies! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It occurs to me that you can do this in-place with a slightly modified heap selection algorithm, which is O(n log k). Although asymptotically "worse" than Quickselect's O(n) complexity, heap select can outperform Quickselect when k is very small in comparison to n. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) for details. But if you're selecting, say, the top 1,000 items from a list of a million, heap select will almost certainly be faster.

Anyway, to do this in place, you build a max-heap (using the standard BuildHeap function) of size k at the front of the array, from the first k items in the array. That takes O(k). Then, you process the rest of the items in the array like this:

```
for (i = k; i < length; ++i)
{
    if (array[i] < array[0])  // If item is smaller than largest item on heap
    {
        // put large item at the current position
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[0];

        // put new item at the top of heap and sift it down
        array[0] = temp;
        SiftDown(0);
    }
}
```

That will take O(n log k) time, but the limiting factor is really how many times you have to perform the code inside the conditional. Only when an item is smaller than the largest item already on the heap does this step take any processing. Worst case is when the array is in reverse sorted order. Otherwise it's surprisingly fast.

When done, the smallest k items are at the front of the array.

You then have to sort them, which is O(k log k).

So the complete procedure is O(k + n log k + k log k). Again, when k is much smaller than n, this is considerably faster than Quickselect.

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to leave a comment explaining what you find wrong about the answer.